# What is the default PostgreSQL Log Format

Tags: postgresql, logging, format

What is the default PostgreSQL log format? Can you provide the official documentation link?

I am trying to build a couple standard parsing statements to extract values, but when looking across the WWW I am seeing many variations and cannot find it in their documentation.

I am looking for something like this:

```
<date_utc> <hostname> postgres[<pid>] : [<group_id>] <sql_error_code> <session_id> <message_type>: <message>
```

Comment: It is specified in `postgresql.conf` and there should be some comments that help explain. Did you look at that file?

Comment: @Nicarus The configuration file only shows all the parameters, it doesn't show how they are rendered in the logs.

Comment: Maybe I am not fully understanding, but those parameters tell PostgreSQL which data will be written ("rendered") to the log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log file format is configured with the [`log_destination`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-DESTINATION) parameter, the default value is `stderr`.  With this format, you adjust the [`log_line_prefix`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-LINE-PREFIX) parameter to specify how the log file looks.

That makes the log virtually impossible to parse unless you know the current setting of `log_line_prefix`.

Alternatively, you could use the [`csvlog` format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-CSVLOG) which is much easier to parse automatically.

Note that the PostgreSQL log file is written in the language set by the parameter [`lc_messages`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LC-MESSAGES), which is not necessarily the same for all databases, so you can end up with a log file written in several different languages.

Comment: Do you know where the official stderr format is documented?

Comment: It is not documented, but after the part that you can configure with `log_line_prefix` follows the log type (something like `LOG` or `DETAIL` or `ERROR` or `FATAL` in the configured language), followed by "`:  `" and the actual message.